# Can I use a self hosted Web-API as Backend for AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway

The AWS API Gateway provides a lot of features managing Access to Web-API, Billing and others.

Is it possible to host a Web-API e.g. on server http://192.191.10.12:99 (that I am controlling) and use the API Gateway as the top level entry point ?

Would be great If someone can reference the right guide or documentation. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use API Gateway for a REST API to connect to an API endpoint, there are a couple of approaches to doing this.

**Public HTTP Endpoint**

The first approach involves the target endpoint being publicly accessible, this might be in AWS or on-premise but its important that API Gateway can speak to it via the public internet.

This allows a specific verb to use a [HTTP endpoint integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/setup-http-integrations.html) to forward requests to that endpoint that are received by API Gateway. Just like other integrations this can change per verb/action combinations.

You can enhance the security by using a [client certificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html) that is validate on your server endpoint, to confirm that API Gateway is the only traffic that is authenticated to speak to your host.

**VPC Link**

The second approach involves either the target endpoint being private, or wanting to remove the need for transit over the public internet.

This requires the setup of a private network load balancer, which has a target group either configured for your instance(s) or to specific IP addresses (this will allow traffic over a VPN/Direct Connect to be load balanced).

Then API Gateway will create a [VPC Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-private-integration.html) between the service and your NLB which is kept entirely within the AWS backbone. The VPC Link will need to be included in your API Gateway configuration just like other integrations.